# How to format image string from a method in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having a class NetworkHandler.dart with a method getImage

This is the class

```
class NetworkHandler{
 String imgUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:5000";
 NetworkImage getImage(String imageName) {
    String url = imgUrl + imageName;
    return NetworkImage(url);
  }
}
```

So when trying to use the getImage method in one of my widgets like this

```
  Widget _buildBottomInfo(BuildContext context,
      {required String ImgUrl}) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      height: 145,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: ImgUrl, //
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
    );
  }


  _buildBottomInfo(
                  context,
     ImgUrl: NetworkHandler().getImage(vendorController.vendor.value.v_banner.toString())
     .toString(),
  ),
```

I got an error showing

```
'Illegal scheme character (at character 13)
NetworkImage("http://10.0.2.2:5000/public/W52xyq4Hkd-refil-store1.jpeg", sc...'
```

but when I use it directly without the getImage method like this

```
'${NetworkHandler().imgUrl + vendorController.vendor.value.v_banner!}',
```

It works fine, and the image is displayed

So how can I use it with the getImage method in my widget?

Comment: Are you able to get the image on error link?

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh error link like this' Illegal scheme character (at character 13)
NetworkImage("http://10.0.2.2:5000/public/W52xyq4Hkd-refil-store1.jpeg", sc...

Comment: Can you include `_buildBottomInfo`

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh Kindly check, it is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing URL that is string on `_buildBottomInfo` and it will be used on `CachedNetworkImage`, everything is fine until now but while doing

```dart
NetworkHandler().getImage(vendorController.vendor.value.v_banner.toString())
     .toString()
```

You are forcing `NetworkHandler` to be a string. While it is not a string, it produces the error.

You can get URL by from `NetworkImage`

```dart
NetworkHandler().getImage(...).url
```

You also make this simpler by making static method,

```dart
class NetworkHandler {
  static const _imgUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:5000";
  static String getImageUrlString(String imageName) {
    String url = _imgUrl + imageName;
    return url;
  }
}
```

Now to use this

```dart
 NetworkHandler.getImageUrlString("rest_imageName"),
```

in your case, `rest_imageName` will be replaced with `vendorController.vendor.value.v_banner.toString()`